# Confused about httpd

Tags: linux, shell

I've lammp (xampp for linux) installed on my machine.
I used "ps aux | grep httpd" to get what my apache act as...?

And I get "nobody" on there...
What actually nobody means?

And, how can I change the owner of folder and it's all subs...?
Thank's before... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nobody` is just as it sounds; a user with minimal permissions.

`chown` can be used to change ownership of a filesystem object. Passing `-R` will make it recursive (*use with caution*).